# Node js webhdfs callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I am using webhdfs library to move file to hdfs (hadoop file system) like:

```
var hdfsConnector = WebHDFS.createClient(this.config());

var localFileStream = fs.createReadStream(sourcePath);
var remoteFileStream = hdfsConnector.createWriteStream(destinationPath);
localFileStream.pipe(remoteFileStream);

remoteFileStream.on('error', function onError (err) {
    //On error 
});

remoteFileStream.on('finish', function onFinish () {
    //On finish
});
```

The problem is that finish callback is triggered in each case i.e. on error and on success, so how can i identify success.